# What is the opposite for "thin-skinned"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

What is the idiom or term for describing a usually respectful and nice person who is not easily offended by others' criticism, advice, jokes, or insults? ( I  know the opposite is "thin-skinned", but I'm not sure if "thick-skinned" is the answer for this question.)

Comment: Yes, "thick-skinned" means that a person is not easily offended (at least not visibly, though you might be wary of turning your back on them after insulting them).

Comment: No, I mean that "thick-skinned" is valid, but (as is always the case with English) one must beware of nuances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**thick-skinned** is absolutely appropriate here.

Google definition:

> **thick-skinned** *adj.* insensitive to criticism or insults.
>
> You can come talk to me about anything, I'm quite thick-skinned it won't take anything you say personally.
>
> He's quite thick-skinned, last week Julie told him that his jokes weren't funny, and that didn't stop him entertaining us with his jokes all night!

Answer (score 2):

**Equable** http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equable

> Definition of equable in English: *adjective*
>   1Not easily disturbed or
>   angered; calm and even-tempered:
>    ::::*he could look sterner than his equable temperament would suggest*

and here are synonyms for **equable** from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/equable):

> = **even-tempered**, calm, composed, agreeable, serene, easy-going, placid, temperate, level-headed, unfazed, **unflappable**, unruffled,
>   imperturbable, unexcitable,